# update panel not working in visual part SP 2013

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio-2013

I added update panel In visual wepart . It has a  button to get list items using c#.

When I click on button I got **The web object may be disposed**

I am trying to figure out the issue but the code working only in debugging! So I think the issue in the update panel

How to use UpdatePanel in SharePoint visual web part?.

Button Code

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepointsite"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["NameList"];
                    dropSite.DataSource = list.Items;
                    dropSite.DataValueField = "Title"; 
                    dropSite.DataTextField = "Title"; 
                    dropSite.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please try to post your code to can help you faster

Comment: @M.Qassas code added

Comment: If you didn't use using what happens? It is working...?

Comment: Yes it worked, what about dispose , How can I do it?